# This `alert` message box shows up in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a simple HTML page with jQuery and it doesn't want to work in Firefox. In Chrome and IE it works perfectly. This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function() 
        { 
            alert();    
        }
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've read on web that the problem could be the docType, but I tried then all. 
The jQuery script file is on the same directory as the HTML file.

Comment: is the jquery file downloaded by browser

Comment: I don't see any BASIC in this question.

Comment: The lesson here is that you saw no `alert` and then jumped to a conclusion about the cause. The wrong conclusion. As a consequence, your question title was wildly incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Alert requires some parameters on FF. Try

```
alert("some text here");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`alert` is not part of any standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.alert), but it's not a stretch to suppose that attempting to `alert` with *no string to display* will avoid a dialog box at all on some browsers.

In fact, I have tested and reproduced this issue on Firefox 20 (and control-tested on Chrome 28) by manipulating [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwCSQ/), removing and re-adding the argument.

### Give `alert` an argument.

```
alert('Some message here.');
```